# Connecting to host machine with non static ip from docker-container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

I want to connect to host from inside the container, given that host ip is non-static.
I don't want to use the host network. I am using docker-compose to manage the containers.

Comment: add your dns server to the container

Comment: @LinPy how can we do it?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/

Comment: your IP might change but docker creates its own network and can be always reached by connecting to 172.17.0.1. You can simply check the docker0 network